# How to deal with System.String[]

Tags: powershell

I am using the below script line to get the IP information of system and then exporting in to a HTML file. But when I export the file the Most of the values of below command comes in System.String[], and I searched the net but not able to find how to deal with this.

> Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | select
>   Description,DHCPServer,IpAddress,IpSubnet,DefaultIPgateway,DNSServerSearchOrder,WinsPrimaryServer,WINSSecindaryServer
>   | ConvertTo-Html > d:\aman.html

When I check the Properties in IPADDRESS using **WMIEXPLORER** tool, these are arrays and I don't know how to manipulate them.

And I want the output in table format so that it can easily fit in to my Reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a calculated field in the `Select-Object` statement and join the array.

Here, `IPAddress` is joined with a semicolon:

**EDIT:** Updated with remaning string array properties, and added a space after semicolon to allow the string to wrap in the displayed HTML

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration| 
    Select-Object Description, DHCPServer, 
        @{Name='IpAddress';Expression={$_.IpAddress -join '; '}}, 
        @{Name='IpSubnet';Expression={$_.IpSubnet -join '; '}}, 
        @{Name='DefaultIPgateway';Expression={$_.DefaultIPgateway -join '; '}}, 
        @{Name='DNSServerSearchOrder';Expression={$_.DNSServerSearchOrder -join '; '}}, 
        WinsPrimaryServer, WINSSecindaryServer|
    ConvertTo-Html > .\temp.htm
```

Comment: No works for me :(, it shows the Ipaddress Coreectly, not IpSubnet, DNSServerSerachOrder etc. can u explain what is System.String[] ..

Comment: `System.String[]` is an array of strings. To display the array in the `ConvertTo-HTML` statement you need to join the strings together as one string. To show other fields that are arrays (IpSubnet, DNSServerSerachOrder etc.), do the same thing I did with IPAddress. The template looks like: `@{Name=$_.<Property Name>; Expression={$_.<Property Name> -join '<Join character(s)>'}}`

Comment: Okies..Great..working..but,,i have an Question {if u dont mind} , when you use `Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | gm IPaddress` in definition is shows **System.String[] IPAddress {get;set;}** , so how u know that in -join ,the join character is **;** not any other.. I want to know you my knowledge purpose to clear my doubts.

Comment: @Aman: the join character is up to you. Is just the character separator that you will see in the html page.

Comment: @Christian is right. You could use `'&#13;&#10;'` to insert an HTML carriage return and line feed. But since `ConvertTo-HTML` escapes the `&` with `&amp;`, you'll have to replace it like `. . .| ConvertTo-Html| foreach {$_ -replace '&amp;','&'} > .\temp.htm`

Comment: **@Christian** and **@Rynant** thanks a lot for explaining and thanks for solving the problem... `Have a nice day` . . .